# testing coverage of other sources files with gcov

Tags: unit-testing, gcov

For a class project I have to use gcov to test coverage of a file that doesn't have a main function, but is called by a file with a main function. So there's a .c file that has all of the library calls we've been writing and then there's a .c file that tests those calls. The problem is if I use gcov it only works with the executable .c file and doesn't show coverage of the function calls in the other .c file.

Does anybody know if there's a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My compile flags were off when compiling my source. I needed to also compile with -lgcov and --coverage

```
gcc --coverage *.c -o main --fprofile-arcs --ftest-coverage -lgcov
```